# defer feature in @this.set() livewire 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In Livewire 2, I could postpone the update by sending the value true in the last parameter, but this possibility is not available in Livewire 3.

What is the alternative for **@this.set('prop', value, true)** in livewire 3 ?

Comment: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties#manipulating-properties

Answer (score 1):

Try to use livewire js events
On your js file:

```
const isEnabled=true;
Livewire.emit('dataChanged',isEnabled);
```

On component php class

```
protected $listeners = ['dataChanged' => 'dataChanged'];
public $isEnabled;

public function dataChanged($data){
$this->isEnabled=$data;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
But my problem was solved by changing the value of true to false 
**@this.set('prop', value, false)**

Answer (score 0):

In livewire 3 you should wrap your `<script></script>` in `@script <script></script> @endscript`. This will give you access to  the `$wire` variable to access your component.

Ref: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#using-javascript

Ref: $wire object: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/javascript#the-wire-object

Then refactor your `@this.set('prop', value, true)` to `$wire.set('prop', value, true)`. Note that `true` is the default value for 'defer' when using `set()`. Setting it to `false` has a different effect in the end.